# Cross-domain conundrum

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp, same-origin-policy

I have researched the Internet to solve the following cross-domain web-client situation without luck:

A client browser with website A loaded wants to download a webpage-stream directly from website B and incorporated the steam into its DOM.

The boundary conditions are:

1. webserver of website B has no special policies for:
   -cross-domain accesses, 
   -and/or special jsonp services.
2. I don't wat to use either:
   -a proxy-service on my webserver, or 
   -using a third server such as http://anyorigin.com/, or 
   -depend on a particular extensions for the browser.
3. I understood that actual browsers don't handle 'X-Frame-Options' different that 'SAMEORIGN'

Do you guys have any feasible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to patch the feed in at the server level.  But at least, you can add a cache so it doesn't pull the feed in every request.

Edit: I'm assuming you don't want iframes

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't iframe in the results of website b? That'd be the first thing I tried...

Comment: An Iframe works under this policy 'X-Frame-Options'  'SAMEORIGN'. I tried it in chrome!